# How to get no. of occurence of a particular word in a column in excel

Tags: excel

I have a excel data

```
     _________________________________________________________________
       |        A                        B               C     |   D   |
|--------------------------------------------------------------|-------|
|  1   |      Device              |    Country    |            |       |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  2   |      Android   tablet    |     iNDIA     |            |       |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  3   |      Android             |     India     |            |       |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  4   |      Android             |   Bangladesh  |            |       |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------|
|  5   |      Android             |    Pakistan   |            |       |
|----------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

When i am using this formula

`=COUNTIF(A2:A5,"Android")`  its returning me `3`.

Thats means its taking only `"Android"`

But i want `"Android tablet"` should also be taken in account that means the result becomes `4`. There may be some wild card method but i dont know that

How can i achieve this?

Comment: Web search: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=excel+countif+wildcard  The very first hit takes you to the documentation, which even gives you an example with wildcards.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`*` is the wildcard in Excel:

```
=COUNTIF(A2:A5,"*Android*")
```